# block pixel shifting in Python/GTK

Tags: python, gtk, bitblt

I want to make a sideways scrolling text box (a "ticker tape" display) using Python 2.6 and gtk+ (as per Centos 6.3).

I have made a timer driven routine that takes a text string and prints it repeatedly while incrementing the offset in the print window. That works but seems to be slightly more processor-intensive than I might like.

Rather than printing the string fully and repeatedly with an incrementing offset - is there a way to use block move acceleration in some way and benefit from the use of "blitting" hardware on most GPU's? I was wondering if the string can be printed to a pixel buffer of some type and then the relevant portion can be "blitted" to screen memory? Any comments or experience would be appreciated.

My target hardware is Intel 945GME based.

Answer (score 1):

> My best attempt (so far) at some code to do this follows. No, I am not
>   very experienced in these things and this is hardly "exemplary code" - but thought I 
>   should share "wot I dun"

```
import gtk
import pango
import glib
import cairo


class Scroller(gtk.DrawingArea):
    def __init__(self, TextString):
        super(Scroller, self).__init__()
        self.offset_x = 0
        self.offset_y = 0
        self.screen_x = 1000
        self.screen_y = 0
# process the y=text string to make an image of it
        self.p = self.create_pango_layout(TextString)
        self.p.set_font_description(pango.FontDescription('Sans 36'))
        attr = pango.AttrList()
        attr.insert(pango.AttrForeground(60535, 60535, 0, 0, -1))
        self.p.set_attributes(attr)
        self.p.set_width(-1)
        self.text_width, self.text_height = self.p.get_size()
        self.text_width = self.text_width / pango.SCALE
        self.text_height = self.text_height / pango.SCALE

#create a pixmap with the data of the pixbuf
        self.pixelbuffer = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB, False, 8,  self.text_width, self.text_height)
        self.pixelbuffer.fill(0) 
        pixmap,_ = self.pixelbuffer.render_pixmap_and_mask()
        self.pgc = pixmap.new_gc()

        pixmap.draw_layout(self.pgc, 0, 0, self.p)
# now copy image back to pixelbuiffer
        self.pixelbuffer.get_from_drawable(pixmap, pixmap.get_colormap(), 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1)

    def initscreen(self):
        print "screen initialised"
        self.window.clear()
        self.update_display()

    def update_display(self):
        offset = -1
# this scrolls the text sideways
        self.screen_x = self.screen_x + offset
        self.window.draw_pixbuf(self.pgc, self.pixelbuffer, self.offset_x, self.offset_y, self.screen_x, self.screen_y)
# and repeat until bored.
        if self.screen_x == -self.text_width: 
            self.screen_x =1000
        return True


# Main program 
class PyApp(gtk.Window): 
    def __init__(self):
        super(PyApp, self).__init__()

        self.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL, gtk.gdk.Color(0, 0, 0))
        self.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
        self.set_title("side scroller")


        scroller_screen=Scroller('Breaking News - scrolling text works! More soon....Olympic Games in London are highly entertaining. No more please!')
        self.add(scroller_screen)       
        self.set_size_request(1000, 100)
        self.show_all()
        scroller_screen.initscreen
# set a 20 millisec scroll refreash timer
        glib.timeout_add(20, scroller_screen.update_display)

PyApp()

gtk.main()
```